# PIG Script to handle nth-1 record

Tags: apache-pig

Input File Structure : records are sorted based on the time stamp
Expected input fiel size will be :2-3TB

```
timestamp 
==============
20141014120523
20141014120534
20141014120537
20141014120542
20141014120549
20141014120555
20141014120565
20141014120570
20141014120512 
...
...
```

Using PIG I need to find the time difference between the Nth record and Nth-1 Record time stamp (20141014120534 - 20141014120523 = 11 secs).
I need to loop through all the records to get the time difference from previous record

**Example Output**

```
0
11
3
5
...
```

Please help me with the right resources/references/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
input.txt
20141014120523
20141014120534
20141014120537
20141014120542
20141014120549
20141014120555
20141014120565
20141014120570

PigScript:
A = LOAD 'input.txt' using PigStorage() as (time:long);
B = RANK A;
C = FILTER B BY rank_A;
D = FILTER B BY rank_A > 1;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE ($0-1),$1;
F = JOIN B BY $0, E BY $0;
G = FOREACH F GENERATE (E::time - B::time);
DUMP G;

Output:
(11)
(3)
(5)
(7)
(6)
(10)
(5)
```